# No module named 'pytesseract'

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

Can't use pytesseract module on my MacOS.
I installed tesseract like this

```
brew install tesseract
```

Then I installed modules

```
pip3 install pillow
pip3 install pytesseract
```

And my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.1.0/bin/tesseract'
```

And I have error:
ModuleNotFoundError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/devyataevya/Desktop/test/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pytesseract
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What python interpreter are you using?

Comment: did you run your code with python3 or python2?

Comment: Try removing your 3rd line, and let Python find it's own path

Comment: I run code with python3 @user898678

Comment: already tried @FreddyMcloughlan

Comment: I suggest opening an issue [here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues) and updating your question here when / if you get some feedback